# Create class that appends all entries to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

I am having trouble with the following task.
I need to create a class that accomodates student id, name and grades of all students. My idea was to create an empty DataFrame to append the values I add to the class.
I came up with the below.

```
class Student:
    
    students_archive = pd.DataFrame(index = 'student_id', columns = ['student_id', 'name', 'grade'])
    
    def __init__(self, s_id, name, grade):
        self.s_id = s_id
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        st = {'student_id': self.s_id,'name': self.name, 'grade': self.grade}
        pd.concat([Student.students_archive, st])
```

I am however getting the following error:

If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

I dont really understand whats wrong and I have looked it all around, can anybody help me? Thanks
I also cant help but think mine is the wrong approach since the task doesnt actually specify that it needs to be a dataframe, just says that I have to 'create a class that accomodate students name, grade, and id, and create methods to add, remove or upgrade the students values'. Perhaps I can do all of that without creating a dataframe?
Thank you

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code, and please provide data. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, i dont really have data to provide...just need help in formatting the class.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so here's an answer.

Running the code shows me 2 errors:

1. This `index = 'student_id'` should be more like this `index = ['student_id']`
2. This `pd.concat([Student.students_archive, st])` does not accept a dictionary rather something like `pd.concat([dataframe_0, dataframe_1])`

Also I think it's better if you add your dataframe inside the `__init__()`.

So it should result in something like:

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, s_id, name, grade):
        self.s_id = s_id
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.students_archive = pd.DataFrame(index = ['student_id'], columns = ['student_id', 'name', 'grade'])
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'student_id': [self.s_id],'name': [self.name], 'grade': [self.grade]})
        new_temp_df = pd.concat([self.students_archive, temp_df])
```

But keep in mind that `temp_df` and `new_temp_df` wil probably be garbage collected so, keep what you want by adding `self.`

As I understand it:

```
template = pd.DataFrame(index = ['student_id'], columns = ['student_id', 'name', 'grade'])
entries = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'student_id': [self.s_id],'name': [self.name], 'grade': [self.grade]})
self.student_df = pd.concat([template, entries])
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Having read your comment and the code you linked, it seems like instantiating each student is out of the scope. You seem to be on the right track though.

1. I would still add the main dataframe inside the `__init__()`, keeps it more tidy imho. You can still Acceess it from outside the class (more below).
2. incorporate the functionality needed through methods (add/remove/update), which you started doing.
3. Whether this approach is correct or not is probably up to your professor and if they forbid libraries like pandas. I don't see anything wrong as it gives you much of what's needed.

So, in code I would suggest something like this:

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self):
        # keep in mind that pandas will add another column to the left for row id (0, 1, 2, etc..)
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['student_id', 'name', 'grade'])
        
    def add_student(self, s_id, nm, gr):
        # a new dataframe is returned from .append() containing the new values, we replace our old on with that
        self.df = self.df.append({'student_id':s_id, 'name':nm, 'grade':gr}, ignore_index = True)

    def remove_student(self, s_id):
        # we are basically, getting a new dataframe without the rows that have s_id as their student_id
        self.df = self.df[self.df.student_id != s_id]
    
    # this could be broken down into 3 methods, 1 for each (id, name, grade)
    def update_student(self, s_id, nm, gr):
        # as i dont know how to update a row, i leave this as a placeholder:
        self.remove_student(s_id)
        self.add_student(s_id, nm, gr)
```

Accessing the dataframe from outside is as easy as:

```
S = Student()
print(S.df)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and its not quite what I am looking for because what I am actually interested in is accessing a dataframe globally by printing Student.student_archive, if i turn it to self.student_archive then the dataframe would contain only the row of the object I am assigning to the class.

Comment: Oh ok, well let me ask this before proceeding, what functionality do you want out of your what you are building? You could have an object for each student, and a master class that aggregates the students data in one dataframe. Or simply 1 class with 1 dataframe, and a function to add new rows. (Or even simpler if you don't require a class, just the dataframe with an accompanied function to insert the data).

Comment: So its a task my uni's exam (which I didnt pass). It was 'Create a class which accomodates the the id, the name and the grade of students, with methods to add, remove students or update a students detail. My idea was to hold a dataframe and add or remove things from it or just update rows but perhaps its the wrong approach.I polished the class further and now every new class instance gets added to the data frame, but I cant seem to be able to create instances through a method. Also the remove_student doesnt work, I would like it to delete the instance as well. https://pastebin.com/7T9u7jvg

Comment: I have updated my answer, if you have any questions as to how something works and why I did it the way I did, let me know!